# How to get hidden state of a polygon

Tags: python, polygon, blender, mesh

In blender you can hide polygons of the mesh via

```
bpy.ops.mesh.hide()
```

and unhide them via

```
bpy.ops.mesh.reveal()
```

But I want to make a switch, that will reveal everything, if something is hidden, and will isolate selected polygons, if everything is revealed. For this I need to know the current state of the polygons. Polygons have a boolean parameter "hide"

```
for p in bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons:
    print(p.hide)
```

But this "hide" flag actually has nothing to do with the hidden state of a polygon. A polygon can be hidden and the "hide" parameter will be false. Also, changing the value of this parameter changes nothing. Looks like it isn't used and developers just forgot to remove it.

So the question is: how do I know in script is a polygon hidden or not?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm stupid. Setting "hide" parameter actually hides them, but doesn't immediately update in viewport. Switching between object mode / edit mode helps.